# PHP PDO to MS SQL Server on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to use PDO to connect to a MS SQL Server. I have tried using this

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=server;database=databaseName", "username", "password");
```

I was reading that sqlsrv is no longer supported. I tried using dblib but that is not working.

I wanted to use PDO because it is supposed to work with various databases but I cannot seem to get it to work with MS SQL.

What is the best way to use PDO with SQL Server on Ubuntu?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Answer (score 19):

I figured it out. I guess I forgot that I never installed the SQL/Sybase drivers on this server.

I installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase
```

Now I can use:

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=sever;dbname=dbname", "username", "password");
```

It's working good now.

Comment: for us (ubuntu 16.04, with PHP7) it is:
   apt-get install php-sybase