# zend framework 2 and sqlserver driver issues

Tags: php, sql-server, database, pdo, zend-framework2

when i try connecting to my sql server database from my zf2 application as shown below,

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'sqlsrv:dbname=album;hostname=192.168.0.20',
        'username'       => 'user',
        'password'       => 'pass',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I get this error,

```
File:
/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php:289
Message:
Connect Error: could not find driver
```

Am i missing something here? Or rather this does not work at all on the linux oriented machines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out this line: `"// PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''"`.
Your connection say you are trying to connect to `MSSQL` and not `MySQL`.

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'sqlsrv:dbname=album;hostname=192.168.0.20',
        'username'       => 'user',
        'password'       => 'pass',
        'driver_options' => array(
           // PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always prep it like this without trouble, using dist files to set the right connection params as you work through deployment:

local config file

```
'database' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'mysql_master' => array( 
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'host' => 'host',
            'dbname' => 'analytics',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass', 
            'charset' => 'UTF8',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'",
            ),              
        ),
    ),
),
```

Then in my Module.php, I define such a factory (in the getServiceConfig array):

```
'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($sm){

     $config         = $sm->get('config');
     $dbParams       = $config['database']['config']['mysql_master'];

     $adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($dbParams);
     return $adapter;
},
```

Hope this helps.  If this doesn't work, something else is going on.. let me know, I can help.

Cheers.
Alex

Comment: Your suggestion is a different way of doing it. MY question was quite different. I wanted to know the sql server database connection issues. MY setup will work just fine for the mysql driver.

Comment: You'll see I'm using Pdo_Mysql, which is what I guessed your connection string wanted to be doing (unless you've got that MySQL-specific PDO init command in there for nothing?).  Tried to fix it for you by giving you a proper config: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html  If your confusion is that you wanted the sqlsrv type (judging by your hostname which I just noticed), then peel that MySQL line for good form, and change your driver type to Sqlsrv. On nix, you can use type 'Pdo' with 'pdotype' => 'dblib' and start your dsn with 'dblib' if you install freetds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the necessary driver installed. I had the same problem with postgres, and this solved it for me:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

However, I am not 100% sure what driver must be installed to make Sql Server work. I did read that it's no longer supported. See this: [PHP PDO to MS SQL Server on Ubuntu Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594945/php-pdo-to-ms-sql-server-on-ubuntu-server). In a nutshell, your best bet is to rather use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase
```

and then connection string:

```
"dblib:host=sever;dbname=dbname"
```

From what I gather, that should connect you to a Sql Server database, but again, I can't gaurantee this because I don't have a setup to test it with. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you some... I'm currently following along to the Zend Framework 2 skeleton application guide. My database parameters needed to be passed in the following way:

```
    'db' => array(
         'driver'   => 'SQLSRV',
         'hostname' => 'SqlServerName',
         'Database' => 'SqlDatabaseName',
         'uid'      => 'UsertoConnectwith',
         'pwd'      => 'Passwordofusertoconnectwith'
     ),
```