# Laravel - PDOException Missing Driver on Ubuntu

Tags: php, database, laravel, odbc

I've developed an application in PHP using Laravel, which I now want to deploy via a VPS.

I've followed [DevMarketer's Guide](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/) to deploy the application, and I've also followed [This Microsoft's SQL Server Tutorial on Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/).

So far, my application is appearing and executing just fine on the domain. However, upon trying to communicate with the database, I get the following error in my log.

> [2017-07-10 14:11:26] local.ERROR: **PDOException**: could not find driver in /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

## PHP --ini

Gives me the following result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-odbc.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_odbc.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

## SQLCMD

It may be useful to specify that when I use the following

```
sqlcmd -S yeah.server.windows.net -U su_root -P sup3rs3qr3t
```

I get a

```
1>
```

Which as I understand it means it authenticated successfully.

However, that error persists in my `laravel.log` file (I clear it before every run so I know I'm not seeing an old error)

I've also tried `php artisan config:clear` and restarting nginx etc.

## config/Database.php

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

'connections' => [
'sqlsrv' => [
'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'charset'  => 'utf8',
'prefix'   => '',
],
];
```

I'd appreciate a bit of help,

thank you all in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594945/php-pdo-to-ms-sql-server-on-ubuntu-server

check if you have the pdo installed (and enabled in php.ini)

Comment: Check your config/database.php file. No driver could be referring to not having your database config in there.

Comment: @Styphon I've updated the post at the bottom.

Comment: @katona.abel - That post is referring to Php5 modules, though. Besides, had the driver not been installed, I doubt command line would work as it does?